# How to get required fields from Products table in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

My Requirement is very simple, I need to fetch only few fields from  products table in bigcommerce. [Products API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products)

**For Example :**

*Current Response output from Bigcommerce:*

```
 {
  "id": 32,
  "keyword_filter": null,
  "name": "[Sample] Tomorrow is today, Red printed scarf",
  "type": "physical",
  "sku": "",
  "description": "Densely pack your descriptions with useful information        and watch products fly off the shelf."
}
```

**My Required output:**

I need only three fields from bigcommerce.

```
{
      "id": 32,      
      "name": "[Sample] Tomorrow is today, Red printed scarf",      
      "description": "Densely pack your descriptions with useful information        and watch products fly off the shelf."
 }
```

Please anyone suggest me, how to get only required fields thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While you can filter the request, you cannot control what fields the API gives in the response.

Just push the appropriate fields into a new array and work with the data there.

```
$myArray['id'] = $decodedResponse->id;
$myArray['name'] = $decodedResponse->name;
$myArray['description'] = $decodedResponse->description;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , But I expect bigcommerce API call itself to return only required fields,

Comment: I understand that. However, that is not how their API works. Their API - like so many others - returns a standard set of fields. It is up to you to work with the ones you want. Why can't you just grab and use those 3 fields after you receive the response?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a way now available ..Please check this out.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#get-a-product

GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{id}

Notes
You can filter the retrieved fields by appending one of the following options to your request:

?include=
?include=@summary
?exclude=
In particular, you can reduce payload size, and improve performance, by excluding the description field.

Mandatory Fields

However, the following fields are always present on product API requests, and cannot be excluded:

id
name
date_modified
primary_image
include

The following sample request will retrieve only the specified date_created, price, and cost_price fields, plus the mandatory fields listed just above:

https://store-et7xe3pz.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/32?include=date_created,price,cost_price